# Save and view multiple Manipulates in one file

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, save

Following a suggestion under [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/270748/11125), I tried to use several `Manipulate`s to record groups of many plots. This is to avoid the painful delay and freezing of saving/displaying all plots together in a Notebook.

I will typically have one `Manipulate` per cell and several independent cells in one Notebook file. The code in each cell might differ a lot or only in a few parameters. Below is a minimal example with three similar cells. I want to save all the plots in one .nb file and reopen to view freely.

Two questions:

1. Conceptual one. Are the plots really saved? I mean when I reopen the .nb file and press the buttons, the plots are being replotted on-site or just from saved ones?
2. Such a .nb file usually suffers from some mutual effects between the cells, although my intention is to make cells entirely independent. It occurs sometimes at the successive evaluation and sometimes after reopening and pressing parameter buttons around. **For instance, the result of Cell 3 can overwrite those of Cell 1 or Cell 2**, i.e., all three cells display the same plots and one can no longer see the correct plots of Cell 1 and Cell 2. As an obvious symptom, without pressing any button, the default output of Cell 1 shows parabolas like $y=-x^2$, but it can be automatically changed to that of Cell 3 with parabolas like $y=x^2$.

---

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
max = 3; m = 1;
Manipulate[
 VectorDensityPlot[{Sin[a x^2 + m y], c Cos[b x - y]}, {x, -max, 
   max}, {y, -max, max}, PlotRange -> Full, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", VectorColorFunction -> None, 
  VectorRange -> All, VectorStyle -> Black, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[ArcTan[#3, #4]/(2 \[Pi]), 0.8] &)], {{c, 0.1},
   0.1, 2, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Row[{Control[{{a, 1}, Range[3]}], Spacer[20], 
   Control[{{b, 1}, Range[4]}]}], SaveDefinitions -> True]
(*CELL 1*)

ClearAll["Global`*"];
max = 3; m = 2;
Manipulate[
 VectorDensityPlot[{Sin[a x^2 + m y], c Cos[b x - y]}, {x, -max, 
   max}, {y, -max, max}, PlotRange -> Full, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", VectorColorFunction -> None, 
  VectorRange -> All, VectorStyle -> Black, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[ArcTan[#3, #4]/(2 \[Pi]), 0.8] &)], {{c, 0.1},
   0.1, 2, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Row[{Control[{{a, 1}, Range[3]}], Spacer[20], 
   Control[{{b, 1}, Range[4]}]}], SaveDefinitions -> True]
(*CELL 2*)

ClearAll["Global`*"];
max = 3; m = -1;
Manipulate[
 VectorDensityPlot[{Sin[a x^2 + m y], c Cos[b x - y]}, {x, -max, 
   max}, {y, -max, max}, PlotRange -> Full, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", VectorColorFunction -> None, 
  VectorRange -> All, VectorStyle -> Black, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[ArcTan[#3, #4]/(2 \[Pi]), 0.8] &)], {{c, 0.1},
   0.1, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Row[{Control[{{a, 1}, Range[3]}], Spacer[20], 
   Control[{{b, 1}, Range[4]}]}], SaveDefinitions -> True]
(*CELL 3*)
```

The three cells differ only in `m` and `c`.

Comment: What you see in the cell expression is what is in the notebook when you save it.  So you could answer question one yourself. Not sure what you are asking in the second question, but have you seen `CellContext`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Description updated. `CellContext` doesn't seem to help or maybe I did it wrongly.

Comment: A simple way to make the manipulations independent would be using different parameters for different manipulations, such as c1,a1,b1 for the first cell,  c2, a2, b2 for the second one and so on. You may then make the following construction: `{{c1, 0.1,"c"}, 0.1, 2, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}` to make all parameters look the same on the panel.

Comment: I usually localize variables like `max` inside `Manipulate` with `Manipulate[..., {{max, 3}, None}]` or `{{max, 3}, ControlType -> None}`, unless I want to change the value of `max`. If I you want to change the value, why not have a control? (Too many controls?) -- This works for me: `CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Manipulate[ ...], "Output", CellContext -> Cell]]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Nice and thanks! So I got your idea of restricting the context or namespace but did it in the wrong way without `CellPrint[]`, which does not work properly although I don't understand.

Comment: I think `CellContext` has to be set in the cell containing `Manipulate` before it appears in the notebook.  When it appears, the FE starts running it and sends things to the kernel to be evaluated. Variables get their contexts set at this point. If `CellContext` has not been set in the cell, `max` and `m` will be created in the ``Global` `` context. (I think that's how it works.)